# Create new list with copied and averaged items from old list

Tags: python, list, numpy, average

I have a main list composed of several sub-lists which are in turn also composed of sub-lists (ie: sub-sub-lists) This is a minimal example of what I mean:

```
a = [[[0,1,2,3], [0,4,5,6]], [[1,1,2,7], [1,4,5,8]], [[2,1,2,9], [2,4,5,10]]]
```

Note that the `0` item in each sub-sub-list indicates the index of the sub-list it is in, the `1` and `2` items are equivalent among the two sub-sub-lists in each sub-lists and the third item varies.

I need to create a new list based on that one by leaving out the zero item, then copying items `1` and `2` from each sub-sub-list (which are equal) and finally averaging the third item. So the new list would look like this:

```
b = [[1,2,6.33], [4,5,8.]]
```

where the zero item is gone, the items `1` and `2` are just copied and the third item is averaged among sub-sub-lists:

```
6.33 = (3+7+9)/3
8. = (6+8+10)/3
```

I'm sure this can be accomplished using `zip` and `np.mean` but I can't get it done. I can accept answers which do not make use of those tools by the way, that's just my intuition of where the answer probalby is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this works:

```
a = [[[0,1,2,3], [0,4,5,6]], [[1,1,2,7], [1,4,5,8]], [[2,1,2,9], [2,4,5,10]]]
arr = np.asarray(a)

b =  arr[:, :, 1:].mean(0)
```

Which relies on the fact that items `1` and `2` of the sub-sub lists are the same, so their mean won't change things.

```
>>> b
array([[ 1.        ,  2.        ,  6.33333333],
       [ 4.        ,  5.        ,  8.        ]])
```

Comment: Amazing answer, even simpler than I expected. Nitpick: how could you make it so the averaged numbers are rounded to say 3 decimals? Thank you!

Comment: You can just use `np.round(b, 3)`

Comment: Won't that round the entire array? I need only the third items to be rounded (my real list is far more complicated than the one I presented in the question)

Comment: Yes it would round the entire array. To do it in-place pass just the last column to `np.round` and give the last column as the output: `np.round(b[:,-1], 3, b[:,-1])`